# Creating an array of objects gives Syntax Error

Tags: java, arrays

Let's just get down to business. I have this line of code:

```
    public static Tile[] tiles = new Tile[400];
```

which is giving me the following error in eclipse

```
    Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
```

Tile is a class in the same project and package of which I want to make an array because I can't think of any other way to do the things in the rest of the program...

I have looked on google and on stackoverflow, but can't find the answer. Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Dirk.

EDIT: Here is the Tile class:

```
    package com.mrdls.invade;

    public class Tile {

        public String name = "";
        public int id = 0;
        public boolean passable = false;

        public Tile(String name, int id){
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;

            if(name == "air"){
                passable = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT2, here is the TilesBlocks class

```
    package com.mrdls.invade;

    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    public class TilesBlocks {

        public static BufferedImage tilesetBlocks;

        public static int pixelsPerTile = 20;

        public int[] ints = new int[20];

        public Tile[] tiles = new Tile[400];

        tiles[0] = new Tile("air", -1);
        /*public static final Tile earth = new Tile("earth", 0);
        public static final Tile stone = new Tile("stone", 1);
        public static final Tile cobblestone = new Tile("cobblestone", 2);
        public static final Tile sand = new Tile("sand", 3);
            public static final Tile sandstone = new Tile("sandstone", 4);
        public static final Tile grass = new Tile("grass", 5);
        public static final Tile woodLog = new Tile("log", 6);
        public static final Tile leaves = new Tile("leaves", 7);
        public static final Tile pumpkin = new Tile("pumpkin", 8);
        public static final Tile melon = new Tile("melon", 9);
        public static final Tile pumpkinCarved = new Tile("carved pumpkid", 10);

        public static final Tile copperOre = new Tile("copper ore", 20);
        public static final Tile tinOre = new Tile("tin ore", 21);
        public static final Tile ironOre = new Tile("iron ore", 22);
        public static final Tile silverOre = new Tile("silver ore", 23);
        public static final Tile goldOre = new Tile("gold ore", 24);

        public static final Tile diamondOre = new Tile("diamond ore", 40);
        public static final Tile emeraldOre = new Tile("emerald ore", 41);
        public static final Tile rubyOre = new Tile("ruby ore", 42);
        public static final Tile sapphireOre = new Tile("sapphire ore", 43);*/

        public TilesBlocks(){
            try{
                TilesBlocks.tilesetBlocks = ImageIO.read(Tile.class.getResourceAsStream("/tileset_terrain.png"));
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some more code? Problem does not seem to be on that line.

Comment: Please show us your Tile class.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but there is not problem in public static int [] tiles = new int[400];. For sure it is in the remaining code. Can you post it?

Comment: your line with the error is not in the class. Show us the class causing the error message

Comment: Use "air".equals(name). that won't solve your problem though.

Comment: Still not there, but the rest.

Comment: Can you paste the file where you are creating the array?

Comment: Thats the error `tiles[0] = new Tile("air", -1);` put it in a method or an initializer block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        tiles[0] = new Tile("air", -1);
```

You can't do this in your class. You need to assign it in your constructor. 
Read the difference between **initialization** and **assignment**.

Initialization of field belongs outside a method, but of course is encapsulated by a class.

Assignment belongs in a method.

or you can initialize like so:

```
Tiles []tiles = new Tiles[]{new Tile("air",-1)} ;
```

And use `.equals` not ==

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem BTW :)

Comment: == compares the addresses of the strings. Using .equals compares the actual string values. And np.

Answer (score 1):

This complete class works fine. I don't see any error in your class and usage.

Here is the complete class

```
package com.test;

public class Tile {

    public static Tile[] tiles = new Tile[400];

    public String name = "";
    public int id = 0;
    public boolean passable = false;

    public Tile(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;

        if (name.equals("air")) {
            passable = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on Red error message, Most likely you are going to see 'Suppress' or 'Clear lint markers' Eclipse sometimes record an error (as you type) and doesn't clear the marks.
Clear Lint Markers and see if the error is gone

Comment: Also in Eclipse 'a red cross' doesn't always mean an Error like I said. I have come across it numerous times when Eclipse marks a line of code as an error (because i had been typing or pasting) and after some delay I fix the error. But Eclipse continue showing it as an error